# Scrape specific data with beautiful soup when there is no unique class or id?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

Im trying to scrape this page with Beautifulsoup.
`https://www.nb.co.za/en/view-book/?id=9780798182539`

How do I target specific elements if they don't have unique class or id?
Is it possible to scrape a `div` based on the value/text in the sibling `div`?

For instance, in the code below, how can I get `9780798182539` if the sibling div is `<p>ISBN:</p>`

```
<div class="row clearfix">
    <div class="col-md-3 noPadding">
        <p>ISBN:</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-9 noPadding">
        9780798182539
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is the complete html:

```
<div class="col-lg-7 col-md-12 col-sm-12 author-details">
    <h2>Step by Step: Counting to 50 </h2>
    <h5>
        <a href="/en/authors?authorId=2163">Cuberdon</a>
    </h5>

    <div class="row clearfix">
        <div class="col-md-3 noPadding">
            <p>ISBN:</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-9 noPadding">
            9780798182539
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row clearfix">
        <div class="col-md-3 noPadding">
            <p>Publisher:</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-9 noPadding">
            Human &amp; Rousseau
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row clearfix">
        <div class="col-md-3 noPadding">
            <p>Date Released:</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-9 noPadding">
            November 2021
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row clearfix">
        <div class="col-md-3 noPadding">
            <p>Price (incl. VAT):</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-9 noPadding">
            R 120.00
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row clearfix">
        <div class="col-md-3 noPadding">
            <p>Format:</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-9 noPadding">
                    <p>Hard cover, 32pp</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `:-soup-contains` to target the `p` tag by its text. Wrap around the `:has` pseudo-class selector, and specify the relationship as direct parent child with a child `>` combinator, to get the immediate parent `div`. Then throw in an adjacent sibling combinator `+`, with `div` type selector, to move to the adjacent, `div`:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

r = requests.get('http://www.nb.co.za/nb/view-book?id=9780798182539')
soup = bs(r.content, 'lxml')
print(soup.select_one('div:has(> p:-soup-contains("ISBN:")) + div' ).text.strip())
```

Comment: thank you, this is perfect, exactly what I needed.

Comment: you are most welcome

Answer (score 1):

Here is the working solution, so far.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = '''
<div class="col-lg-7 col-md-12 col-sm-12 author-details">
    <h2>Step by Step: Counting to 50 </h2>
    <h5>
        <a href="/en/authors?authorId=2163">Cuberdon</a>
    </h5>

    <div class="row clearfix">
        <div class="col-md-3 noPadding">
            <p>ISBN:</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-9 noPadding">
            9780798182539
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row clearfix">
        <div class="col-md-3 noPadding">
            <p>Publisher:</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-9 noPadding">
            Human &amp; Rousseau
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row clearfix">
        <div class="col-md-3 noPadding">
            <p>Date Released:</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-9 noPadding">
            November 2021
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row clearfix">
        <div class="col-md-3 noPadding">
            <p>Price (incl. VAT):</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-9 noPadding">
            R 120.00
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row clearfix">
        <div class="col-md-3 noPadding">
            <p>Format:</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-9 noPadding">
                    <p>Hard cover, 32pp</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
'''
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
div_text =soup.find('div',class_="col-md-9 noPadding")
print(div_text.get_text(strip=True))
```

Output:

```
9780798182539
```

Comment: thank you, this work for getting the isbn number. However, it still uses a class which is not unique, which is why the answer from QHarr is 'more correct' Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You could do a `find_all` on the main divs with class `row clearfix`, then filter on the divs that contain the string `ISBN`, and do a `find` on that div for the div with class `col-md-9 noPadding`. It would like this in list comprehension:

```
[i.find('div', class_='col-md-9 noPadding').get_text().strip() for i in soup.find_all('div', class_='row clearfix') if 'ISBN:' in i.get_text()][0]
```

Output:

```
9780798182539
```

Comment: Thank you, I am new to python, and not familiar with the code starting with a square bracket. Sorry my bad that this is not the best answer for me. Thank you though.